# Vertically center a heading tag and a heading pseudo selector's content

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

Another vertical alignment question...

Given the following,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="thing">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et tempus mauris. Vivamus imperdiet congue iaculis.</h2>
</div>

<div class="thing">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et tempus mauris.</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thing{
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    width: 625px
}
h2{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.thing:before{
    background: red;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
}
```

What do I need to do in order to have the text and the red box vertically centered? This should work for headings of any height.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3n9xgdy/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `position:Absolute` that breaks the inline-block behavior. Instead use some trick to [fight the space between inline-block elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) and be sure the two elements can be aside on the containers width. Try this:

```
.thing{
    font-size:0; /*ADD*/
}
h2{
    /*margin: 0 0 0 40px; REMOVE*/
    width:585px; /*ADD*/
}
.thing:before{
    /*position: absolute; REMOVE*/
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3n9xgdy/10/)**

Comment: Great stuff. Shame this doesn't work for fluid layouts though.

Comment: maybe Could use percentage @verism with calc

Comment: That'll do nicely - a make-do IE8 solution will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question has *two* answers.

Here's solution **one**: (Make the red box equal the height of the `.thing` content.

```
.thing{
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    position: relative; // Make .thing:before relate it's position to this
    width: 625px
}
h2{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
.thing:before{
    background: red;
    content: '';
    height: 100%; // Height will equal .thing height
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
}
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/s3n9xgdy/8/)

**Second** solution: (Make text center vertically)

```
.thing{
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    min-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 625px
}

h2{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.thing:before{
    background: red;
    content: '';
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s3n9xgdy/12/)